# AngularJs : How to merge two or more scope into single scope

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Actually am sending the data from registration form with multiple scopes ie (veh_register,noofpass,avilableData,foundedClass).......

Every scope object has data  like 
        veh_register :{ "vin" : vin89, "vplnum" :AR 890S, "uni" :proxu}
        noofpass : { noofpass : 900}
        availableData : {"Class" : 9009, "name" : manish}
        etc...... like that

Then how to combine them as single scope object to send it over $http.Post

Here is Clear Cut Code .........

**Controller Method In AngularJs**

$scope.vechicle_Register=function(veh_register,noofpass,avilableData,
                  foundedClass,selectedOption1,selectedOption2){

```
  **How to merge these veh_register+noofpass+avilableData+...........**
     Into single Scope that send it from here to Target .........

   $http.post("interface.php?action=sendVehRegDetails").then(function(result) {                 
           $scope.year=result['data'];
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `extend` function in Angular:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

> Extends the destination object dst by copying all of the properties
>   from the src object(s) to dst. You can specify multiple src objects.

Comment: is it possible for extend with multiple sources scopes to single dest